# How to represent multiple-output logic circuits in tree-based genetic programming

Tags: ai-design, applications, evolutionary-algorithms, logic, genetic-programming

Consider the following digital logic circuit, which has multiple inputs and one output:

[image: Digital logic circuit drawn using Logisim]

The logic circuit above can be represented in tree form:

[image: Tree drawn using Graphviz]

This tree representation could then be used in a tree-based genetic programming framework to evolve the circuit. For example, this tree could be represented as a Lisp list `(or (and A B) (not C))`, which could then be used with the [Little LISP](http://www.genetic-programming.org/gplittlelisp.html) genetic programming framework from John R. Koza's *Genetic Programming* textbook.

However, I now want to deal with digital logic circuits that have more than one output. For example, in the half-adder circuit below, there are two outputs $S$ and $C$, each of which is affected by both inputs $A$ and $B$.

[image: Half adder]

<sub>(Image source: [SICP by Abelson et al. Section 3.3.4 A Simulator for Digital Circuits](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node64.html). [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/))</sub>

How do I represent and evolve such a circuit in tree-based genetic programming? How do I represent the circuit above as a tree that could then be used to evolve the circuit using a tree-based genetic programming framework?

Comment: Maybe you can do this with a custom function that gets $s$ and $c$ as input and that would produce the final return type, i.e. a binary vector.

Comment: @nbro Thank you for the suggestion, but how would such a tree look like exactly? With the binary vector return type, $S$ and $C$ can each be influenced by either $A$ or $B$ but not both. That is the consequence of a tree representation. Perhaps I am not fully understanding your suggestion because I don't see how it could represent things like half-adders (shown in the question) and flip-flops.

Comment: I didn't realise that you didn't want both A and B to affect both S or C, because you didn't explain this in the post. In any case, my suggestion was more about how you could possibly deal with 2 outputs. You can could create a function like `id(s, a) = [s, a]`, and the output of the circuit/tree is of type `list`. Here, `id` is the custom function that you need to add to you function set, in addition to `and`, `or` and `not`. If I have some time, later, I will try to create a simple proof-of-concept that illustrates my idea.

Comment: @nbro Sorry for not making that clear. In the half-adder circuit shown in the question, The output at $S$ is affected by both inputs $A$ and $B$. Similarly for the output at $C$.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. My suggestion above still applies.